# Convergence of $\exp(i x a_n)$ and $\exp(i y a_n)$ implies convergence of $a_n$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $a_n\in\mathbb R_{\geq0}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ is a sequence such that there exist two real numbers $x,y\neq0$ with $\frac xy \in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ such that $$\exp(i x a_n)$$ and $$\exp(i y a_n)$$ converge.

Do the $a_n$ also have to converge?

I don’t think so because we have convergence of $a_n \pmod 2x\pi$ and $a_n \pmod 2y\pi$, but it seems that I can keep adding some multiple of $2\pi$ to $a_n$ without changing $\exp(a_n i x)$ and $\exp(a_n i y)$ that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any such numbers $x$ and $y$ we shall construct a
sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such that $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\lim }%
e^{ixa_{n}}$ exists and $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\lim }e^{iya_{n}}$
exists but $\{a_{n}\}$ does not converge.

Assume that $x,y>0$. We can find positive integers $p_{n}q_{n}$
such that $\left\vert \frac{x}{y}-\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}\right\vert <\frac{1}{%
q_{n}^{2}}$. [Hardy and Wright, Theorem 1.71] Let $a_{n}=\frac{2\pi q_{n}}{y}
$. Then $\left\vert e^{ixa_{n}}-e^{2\pi ip_{n}}\right\vert \leq \left\vert
xa_{n}-2\pi p_{n}\right\vert =\left\vert \frac{x}{y}2\pi q_{n}-2\pi
p_{n}\right\vert =2\pi q_{n}\left\vert \frac{x}{y}-\frac {p_n} {q_n}\right\vert <\frac{2\pi }{%
q_{n}}\rightarrow 0$. Hence $e^{ixa_{n}}\rightarrow 1$. Also $e^{iya_{n}}=1$
for all $n$. But $\{a_{n}\}$ is not convergent.